# Custom event with two decoded values

Tags: elm

I'm trying to write a custom event which sends two decoded values to `update`. `on "mousedown"`, I'd like to inform `update` about the position of the mouse as well as the dimensions of the DOM element.

Here's what I've tried, but doesn't work:

```
dragMeListItem : Item -> Html Msg
dragMeListItem item =
    div
        [ on "mousedown" (Decode.map (\posit -> (Decode.map (\rect -> DragStart posit rect item) decodeRectangle)) Mouse.position)
        , attribute "class" "drag-me"
        , sharedStyles
        , style
            [ ( "background-color", item.color )
            , ( "border", "1px solid #DD0848" )
            ]
        ]
        [ text "Drag Me!"
        , br [] []
        , text (toString item.value)
        ]
```

-

```
decodeRectangle : Decode.Decoder Rectangle
decodeRectangle =
    let
        rectangle =
            DOM.target
                :> DOM.boundingClientRect
    in
        rectangle
```

-

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        DragStart xy rectangle item ->
            let
                xY =
                    Debug.log "xy:" xy

                consoleRectangle =
                    Debug.log "rectangle:" rectangle

                consoleItem =
                    Debug.log "item:" item
            in
                { model
                    | draggingItem = Just ( item, rectangle )
                    , drag = Just (Drag xy xy)
                }
                    ! []
```

-
The compiler error is:

> The type annotation for `dragMeListItem` does not match its
>   definition.
>
> 362| `dragMeListItem : Item -> Html Msg`
>
> The type annotation is saying:
>
> ```
> Item -> Html Msg
> ```
>
> But I am inferring that the definition has this type:
>
> ```
> Item -> Html (Decode.Decoder Msg)
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem originates in your nested use of `Decode.map` in the `"mousedown"` line. Try using `andThen` instead:

```elm
(Mouse.position `Decode.andThen` \posit ->
    decodeRectangle `Decode.andThen` \rect ->
        Decode.succeed (DragStart posit rect item))
```

Comment: The 1st element has this type:

    Decode.Decoder Msg

But the 2nd is:

    VirtualDom.Property a

Hint: All elements should be the same type of value so that we can iterate
through the list without running into unexpected values.

Comment: Ah I forgot the on "mousedown". Thanks for the help!